# Q: How to open pdf files with siri?

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit

I want siri to open pdf files that are stored into an app.
Is there a way to do this?

Siri -> open pdf file xyz

Thanks

Comment: Try this https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/enabling-siri-integration-sirikit/ and use your app like note app

Answer (score 0):

First you need to write an app to render pdfs. Then you need add Document extension to that app to handle opening pdfs. Then you need to add siri extension to handle voice commands.

Comment: I already have an app which loads pdfs in a pdfviewer, i should only add siri externsion?